# How to get rendered image paths from the ElementAPI?

Tags: entrymodel, plugin-elementapi

I'm wanting to return HTML content via the ElementAPI. I seem to be able to do this with the following `elements.php`:

```
'endpoints' => [
    'api/trials.json' => [
        'elementType' => 'Entry',
        'criteria' => ['section' => 'trials'],
        'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
            return [
                'summary' => ($entry->summary ? $entry->summary->getRawContent() : false),
                ...
            ];
        },
    ]
]
```

It's just that the `getRawContent()` returns the following in the JSON:

```
"summary": "<p><img src=\"{asset:46:url}\"…
```

When I'm expecting:

```
"summary": "<p><img src=\"/images/myimage.png"…
```

Should I be using a different method to get to the content, or do I need to run the content through some kind of transformation?

Thanks in advance,

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than calling `getRawContent()`, just explicitly cast your Rich Text field data into a string:

```php
'summary' => ($entry->summary ? (string) $entry->summary : false),
```